# ruby search within an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array os users called, strangely enough, @users.

Is it possible to search WITHIN this array to further narrow down the results. What I am trying to do is the following

```
@users.where(:gender => nil)
```

and end up with a smaller array of users so I can report missing data. is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
@users.select{|x| x.gender.nil?}
```

Or do the inverse (if you have no falsey gender)

```
@users.reject(&:gender)
```

If `@users` is a collection of objects you retrieve from a database, you most certainly can do something like:

```
@users.pluck(:gender)
```

This get all the non-nil values for most database adapters.